# AWS-sfn , Is there any way to stop scheduled step functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

Im developer who is new to AWS.

While configuring step functions, I found there are some senarious that there could be multiple step functions instance executed because of timer I've set.

for the step function that I configured follows below process

1. wait 2 minute
2. execute lambda function

since there is timer in my step function, there could be some cases that, step function might invoked multiple times at a time.

the thing is that, I wan't to guarantee that on execution queue, only one step function in on.

so if any other step function gets invoked, while step function in on running(timing), I wan't to terminate step function that just got invoked. is there any way to list step functions that are executing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prevent an execution from starting, but you can list the executions at the start of your Step Function, and exit early if a running execution is found.

The [ListExecutions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_ListExecutions.html) API lists the executions for a given state machine ARN.  Call it in a Task, setting the `statusFilter` to `RUNNING` to return only in-progress executions.  You'll get back a list of matching [execution items](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_ExecutionListItem.html).  All you care about is whether the length > 0.

Finally, insert a Choice state.  If there are running items, exit.  If no running items, continue with the execution.

Comment: Just the answer that I wanted! thanks for advise:)